# Can you hide tab bar with 1 tab and show it on multiple tab on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

### So It should works like this:

On 1 tab, the vscode auto hide the tab bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH3Rc.png

On multi tab, vscode shows the tab bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaHZa.png

> This is my first ever stackoverflow post so if it's suck, please forgive it